# Acumatica Rest API Endpoint for Customer Contract

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to fetch Customer Contract via Acumatica Rest API. I am working on the Acumatica instance version 20.110.0017. I am using the `Default` endpoint with API version  `18.20.001`. But I am just unable to find the entity for Customer Contract (CT301000).

I checked at Web Service Endpoints but couldn't find it there. Should we create a custom endpoint for this or are there some other options?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not provided as part of the Default endpoint. You'll have to write it on your own.

Comment: Thanks, @Rick. Appreciate your help. :)